# How to customize the "Remove" button in a multiple field (collection)

Tags: entities

So, you have a field (collection, it's the same there) defined with unlimited values, and thus have an "add more" button and a row per distinct value. Let's call the field `termine`.

Now you have to theme the "remove" button in each row, e.g. to change the text to an imagebutton, and you wonder why your usual `$form['field_termine']['und'][$k]['remove_button']['#value']="Kill";` in `xxx_form_alter` does not stick when adding another row via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy, but it took me a couple of hours wading through Drupal Core nevertheless:

```
foreach($form['field_termine']['und'] as $k=>$v) {
  if(!is_numeric($k)) //we only want the individual items...
    continue;
  $form['field_termine']['und'][$k]['remove_button']['#value']="Kill";
}
```

Note that you will get in trouble with multi-language support with this, YMMV.